# Can textmate arrange my code into readable columns?

Tags: textmate

I like to indent repetitive lines of code so they are easy to look at and see small differences. As an example, this is hard to read:

```
address = "1800 Washington St."
name = "George McGoo"
user_type = "admin"
```

but this is easy to read:

```
address   = "1800 Washington St."  
name      = "George McGoo"  
user_type = "admin"
```

Is there a way to do this in Textmate without wearing out my space bar?

EDIT: Thanks to Meryn for the Align Assignment solution. I was hoping for something more general-purpose that I could use to align text like this css:

```
#anim_customer_panel_shadow           { left: 341px; top: 389px; }
#anim_customer_panel_3                { left: 394px; top: 260px; }
#anim_customer_panel_highlight_3      { left: 391px; top: 266px; }
#anim_customer_panel_3_text_highlight { left: 451px; top: 272px; }
```

Answer (score 2):

The command you're looking for is "align assignments".

Get to it by opening the bundle item selector with <kbd>⌃ ⌘ T</kbd>, then search. Or use <kbd>⌥ ⌘ ]</kbd> directly.

Comment: This is great, but I am looking for something more general (see edit).

Comment: I don't think Textmate can do that. You may be able to hack the Ruby code for the alignment command. It seems doable, although I'm helpless when it comes to regexes. :)

Comment: This is at least what I was looking for, if not the OP.